# How to deal with null parameters in ui event handlers where null makes no sense

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

Before I updated my dart version to support only non-null that code was working fine:

```
Radio(
              value: ExcerciseType.weight,
              groupValue: type,
              onChanged: (ExcerciseType value) {
                appState.exerciseType = value;
              },
            ),
```

Now the compiler complaints:

```
"The argument type 'void Function(ExcerciseType)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(ExcerciseType?)?'.",
```

This would fix it:

```
 onChanged: (ExcerciseType? value) {
                    appState.exerciseType = value as ExcerciseType;
      },
```

but that fix is not logical at all. With the as cast I just say value might be null at runtime and appState.exerciseType can accept null values but that is not true at all! appState.ExerciseType is of type ExcerciseType and not ExcerciseType?.

What do I not understand here?

Comment: I will do `if(value!=null)` instead of `as`

Answer (score 0):

`onChanged: (ExcerciseType value){}` means you will get non-nullable value. But

`onChanged: (ExcerciseType? value){}` means you will receive nullable `ExcerciseType` date.

The default `onChanged:` provide nullable data.

> `ValueChanged<T?>? onChanged`

We can have nullable radio button, means it will actually return null after selecting one. And it is useful for some cases. This snippet show you can have null as return. Here, 1st radio button will return null.

```dart
 int? value;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
          children: List.generate(
        5,
        (index) => Radio<int?>(
          value: index == 0 ? null : index,
          groupValue: value,
          onChanged: (int? v) {
            print(v);
            setState(() {
              value = v;
            });
          },
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

You can directly use `!` if you're certain about non-nullable data.

```dart
Radio<ExcerciseType>(  
     onChanged: (ExcerciseType? value) {
      appState.exerciseType = value!;      
     }
   )
```

More about [`onChanged`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Radio/onChanged.html) and [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Comment: NO that generic type on the Radio did not fix it. Still the same error...

Comment: Thanks, that was my fault,  it will always provide nullable data on callback